# Exception occurs while check in the document in oracle ucm web centre

Tags: oracle, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I am trying to check in a document in Oracle UCM. Document check in is failed with below error. Complete error stack trace is as below.

intradoc.common.ServiceException: !csServiceDataException,CHECKIN_NEW_SUB,addFiles!$

[image]

Comment: Does this always occur? Are you able checkin any files? Are you using a profile/rule? If you turn on system and systemdatabase tracing, clear the server output, run a checkin, then view the output, it should tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Previously it was working fine. Yes i have different profile and for each profile we have rule. But check in failed for every profile.

Comment: What does this error means. Caused By: intradoc.data.DataException: !csFsStorageRuleMissing,DispByContentId

Comment: You are missing a FileStoreProvider storage rule. See here for more info: https://blogs.oracle.com/ecmarch/when-is-the-default-storage-rule-not-really-the-default-storage-rule

Comment: thanks alor Jonathan Hult.... you are right this fixed my problem. kudoosss